# Storing Function in json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I'm using ng2-smart-table library and need to apply a pipe against a row. The doc specifies to use a property `valuePrepareFunction` to store a function as such

```
settings = {
      columns: {
        buildQty: {
          title: 'buildQty'
        },
        created: {
          title: 'created',
          valuePrepareFunction: (created) => {
            return this.datePipe.transform(new Date(created), 'dd MMM yyyy');
          }
        },
        username: {
          title: 'User Name'
        },
        email: {
          title: 'Email'
        }
      },
    };
```

The problem I have is that this settings comming from my backend (Django rest framework). How can I store this exact same method as a json object?

Comment: Stringify the function and `eval` it back into existence. JK; don't. Why would you need to store the function?

Comment: It's because the table is created by calculations performed in the backend, I might have a column with such need or not.

Comment: You can't store a function in JSON (unless as a string with source code, but as @kelly said -- don't do that). But you can prepare several typical functions, give them names (IDs), and then pass around these names. So, backend could produce a string like `prepare_date_dd_MMM_yyyy` (or even better, `prepare_date_short`), and frontend upon receiving this config, will replace IDs with local functions. Maybe you can pass some parameters along (like date format). Or backend can return literally `.js` file with functions, but that sounds like an overkill.

Comment: In any case, it seems that you backend knows too much about your frontend -- ideally it should produce easily consumable and transformable data, but apparently it knows you're going to use `ng2-smart-table`... That's a lot of coupling across server/client boundary, I'd try to eliminate that ASAP.

Comment: your answer makes sense, I'll try ids. I want to make my frontend as generic as possible and let the backend have control on how the frontend is configured.
I don't see what's wrong with sending the table settings with an API, it's easier to manage a configurable solution in the long run rather than having to modify the backend and the frontend.